# Using "emulator -avd", how to get indication that "boot completed"?

Tags: android-emulator, adb

I am launching Android emulators from command line. I want to make sure that the emulator finishes launching, before i am trying to manipulate it. How can i wait until for command's output prints "boot completed"? I tried using

```
& adb wait-for-device
```

but it won't help.

The command lines i tried to use:

```
emulator -avd <name_of_emulator>
```

and

```
emulator -avd <name_of_emulator> & adb wait-for-device
```

Once an emulator finishes loading, the output is:

```
emulator: INFO: boot completed
```

but i can't catch it when launching the command line from a script.

Note: i am able to catch the output of the command

```
emulator -list-avds
```

probably because it returns right away.
But launching an emulator takes more time.

Edit:
Using ProcessBuilder.start(), the command line is being executed but the output never returns. It seems to take the process forever to finish being executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83726/how-to-adb-wait-for-device-until-the-home-screen-shows-up